# Creating LinkButtons Programmatically with ServerSide Event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, event-handling

I'm trying to create multiple LinkButtons and wire then to a single event handler on the server. The link buttons render fine but when I check the rendered html theres no __doPostBack;

Here is my code:

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();                        
lb.ID = "index" + loopIndex;
lb.Text = "click me";
lb.Click += new EventHandler(lb_Click);
lb.RenderControl(writer);
```

and the event handler ofcourse:

```
void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Take into account that this is in PageLoad and inside a loop.

Comment: What is 'writer' in your code ?

Comment: @Muhammad: sorry writer is my HtmlTextWriter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `lb.RenderControl(writer);`  and if you use  `form1.Controls.Add(lb);` it will work.

**Reason:** Since you are Rendering your control as a HTML Writer and HTML is added in the output and no event handler work!!